# Remainder width div that must fit it's content?

Tags: css, html, layout

I want to do this.

[image]

I have changing wrapper widths (sometimes it's 100%, sometimes it's a fixed width). Sidebar content is designed to be fixed 250px width, content should be flexible. But when I set content to be `{ width: 100%; }` it just don't fits it's overflowing content.

Comment: Only scripted solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the questing had a bad wording, anyway, just I implemented with CSS.

`content` div can be 100%, but it's `margin-right` should set to `(siderbar.marginLeft + sidebar.width + sidebar.marginRight)`. With 100% it has an explicit width, thus it will fit it's content.

See [eppz.eu/blog](http://eppz.eu/blog/) between 660px and 960px.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for, you can't do it by css/html alone. I'd use javascript to get the wrapper width, then subtract the width of the fixed elements and asign that to the value of the content div. See below:

> var wrapW = document.getElementById("wrapper").clientWidth;
>
> var contW = wrapW - (sideWidth + marginWidths);
>
> document.getElementById("content").style.width = contW+"px";

Obviously in the example above you'd be inserting a fixed value for sideWidth and marginWidths...

Comment: :( Sorry to hear, thanks for clarification. I thought there is some workaround maybe with additional divs or something...

Comment: I wish there was but afraid not :(
Give the js a try, I've just used it to do something very similar to what you want and it's working well. (If it works for you don't forget to click this as the right answer :)

Comment: Will clientWidth contain the value determined by media queries?

Comment: No 100% on what you mean, but wrapW is going to store the value (which is prob not what you were asking) and clientWidth is the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but NOT the vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered), the border or the margin.

Comment: In the code above, shouldn't we set the content.style.width in the end?

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. As I experienced along, it turned out it can be achieved with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 calc can do this.

```
#content {width: calc(100% - 250px);}
#sidebar {width: 250px;}
```

Make sure that the browsers you need support this property. [Here](http://caniuse.com/calc) are the supported browsers. and don't forget the browser-specific prefixes. Like so:

```
#content {
  width: 700px; /* Fallback for older browsers */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

I highly advise you to use border-box to work with calc, it makes everything a lot easier.

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to increase the content size.. you need to increase the size of the outermost div also. Otherwise content div and fixed div will not align smoothly. You can do it by script.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the question, think it was misleading. Wrapper is not to be dependent on the content size. The opposite, content should be fit into the remainder space.